# Collapse responsive navbar on angular 7

Tags: html, angular, web, responsive-design, navbar

Hi im using navbar in angular 7 and i need to collapse it on another page location click, when i resize my browser or when i use my app on mobile the navbar put 3 bars icon for display menu, when i click on another place in the app the menu still shown, how can i collapse the menu ?

here is my HTML file.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sub-navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="subenlaces">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a data-toggle="collapse"routerLink="/">Inicio</a></li>
                <li *ngFor="let item of menu" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                        aria-expanded="false">{{item.titulo}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li  *ngFor="let subitem of item.secundario">
                            <a routerLink="{{subitem.url}}">
                                {{subitem.titulo}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

...
...
```

here is the menu, if i click on white section the menu still shown, i need to clic the 3 bars icon again to collapse it.
How can i collapse it on click another element or white space?

[image]

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is happening is that your data-toggle is only assigned to your navigation bar and the javascript that controls whether the nav menu is open or closed is only triggered when that HTML element is being clicked.

If you want to be able to click outside of the nav menu to toggle the nav menu back, you would want to use a modal design pattern. What that means is that you want an element that hovers over the page that has a light coloring but is below the search interface you have on the page. Here is a CodePen with a simple Modal example(https://codepen.io/ifelawal/pen/oNzEvJm).

What you want to note is line 2 in the JS stores the modal

```js
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
```

On line 11, the modal gets placed on top of the whole page when the button is clicked

```js
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

Then on line 20 in the JS the modal is removed when they click outside of the modal-content

```js
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

this looks for a click outside of the modal element to toggle the modal to disappear. There might be more people with specific angular knowledge to help with this, but until they arrive, I would say searching up modal toggle for angular might help you get closer to the interaction you want.

Comment: I did something similar but using @ViewChild instead getElementById,also i removed class 'X' (expanded menu class) from navbar when i click outside the navbar, it works!.  Thank you